# On cascading linear systems

Tags: signal-processing, linear-control

From chapter 5 of Steven W. Smith's [The Scientist and Engineer's Guide to Digital Signal Processing](https://www.dspguide.com/ch5/5.htm),

---

[image: commutative property for linear systems]

---

I understand that linearity is commutative according to Smith. If  two matrices, $A$ and $B$, each representing a linear system, why  is two matrix multiplication not commutative? These two facts seem contradictory. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: The commutativity of LTI systems seems to ultimately follow from the commutativity of multiplication in the real numbers after transforming the system, not the commutativity of all linear operations (which is not true in general)

Comment: In maths,  I do not think that there is a definition of "linear matrix". If you think there is could you state the definition?

Comment: I just mean that matrix is itself linear in linear algebra.

Comment: Please Let me know how it is fixed.

Comment: Are these LTI systems? Static or dynamic?

Comment: Are you familiarized with state-space realizations?

Comment: Take a look at chapter 1 of [this book](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Linear_Systems_Theory/O3OYDwAAQBAJ).

Comment: Please put the @ and after that, the name of the user, in order to read your comment. @HuynWooRyu

Answer (score 1):

This only holds in general for SISO systems. For MIMO systems (akin to matrices), the commutative property does not need to hold. Consider two systems with shapes $1\times 2$ and $2\times 1$, the size of the product is either $1\times 1$ or  $2\times 2$ depending on the order.